# 4D TQFT construction from a modular tensor category

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, category-theory, quantum-field-theory, topological-quantum-field-theory

I know the construction of 3D topological quantum field theory (TQFT) from a modular tensor category.

I heard that we can even (mathematically) construct  4D TQFT from a modular tensor category. I would like to know how to construct it.

I'd like to study it but I don't know how to search references. Is there any good word to search this 4D TQFT? Or could you suggest references?

I also want to know if there is another mathematically constructed 4D TQFT and how it is called.

Thank you in advance.